# Kentico document query API always returns empty result

Tags: content-management-system, kentico

I have the following query:

```
var newsItems = tree.SelectNodes()
                .Types(pageTypesArray)
                .Path(path)
                .OrderBy(orderBy)
                .CombineWithDefaultCulture(false)
                .Page(page, count)
                .OnCurrentSite()
                .NestingLevel(-1)
                .Culture(CurrentDocument.DocumentCulture)
                .InCategories(categories)
                .TopN(topN)
                .Where("ListableDocumentImage is not null AND ListableDocumentImage != ''")
                .Columns(columns);
```

Which translates like so:

```
WITH AllData AS 
(
    SELECT  TOP 6 * for brevity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [NewsOccurrenceDate] DESC) AS [CMS_RN] 
FROM View_CMS_Tree_Joined AS V WITH (NOLOCK, NOEXPAND) INNER JOIN SOS_News AS C WITH (NOLOCK) ON [V].[DocumentForeignKeyValue] = 
[C].[NewsID] AND V.ClassName = N'News' LEFT OUTER JOIN COM_SKU AS S WITH (NOLOCK) ON [V].[NodeSKUID] = [S].[SKUID] 
WHERE [NodeSiteID] = @NodeSiteID AND (([DocumentCanBePublished] = 1 AND ([DocumentPublishFrom] IS NULL OR [DocumentPublishFrom] <= @Now) 
AND ([DocumentPublishTo] IS NULL OR [DocumentPublishTo] >= @Now)) 
AND [NodeAliasPath] LIKE @NodeAliasPath AND [DocumentCulture] = @DocumentCulture 


**AND 0 = 1)** <<<------------------- WHERE DID THIS COME FROM?????
) 
SELECT  *, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM AllData) AS [CMS_TOT] 


FROM AllData 
WHERE CMS_RN BETWEEN 4 AND 6 
ORDER BY CMS_RN
```

Has anyone ever come across anything like this before? I can't figure out why they're sticking in the `AND 0=1` in my where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Properly structuring your document API call will help with this. In your query results, you can see your `WHERE` condition is not even being added so it does make a difference the order of the methods being called.

For instance:

```
var newsItems = tree.SelectNodes()
                .Types(pageTypesArray)
                .Path(path)
                .Where("ListableDocumentImage is not null AND ListableDocumentImage != ''")
                .TopN(topN)
                .OrderBy(orderBy)
                .CombineWithDefaultCulture(false)
                .Page(page, count)
                .NestingLevel(-1)
                .Culture(CurrentDocument.DocumentCulture)
                .InCategories(categories)
                .OnCurrentSite()
                .Columns(columns);
```

Comment: funnily enough removing the InCategories() call and adding it to my where statement removed the 0=1 part. I don't see it mentioned in the documentation about the order. Is this a general lync thing?

Comment: Categories in general are a very sore point with me and Kentico, doesn't seem to be very friendly from a webpart and API standpoint.  Not sure about the LINQ or not but know order is important with Kentico API